# How to a order a list of records based on how many of their associated records match records in a given array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Sorry if the title's unclear, I didn't know how better to phrase it.

I have a model "Playlist" which has_many and belongs_to another model "User", through an intermediary model "PlaylistUser".

Let's say I'm on the page of a given Playlist (`@playlist`), and `@users = @playlist.users`. How can I list all the other Playlists, ordered by how many Users they share with `@playlist`?

So if `@playlist.users = ["joe","nick","bob"]`, `<playlist2>.users = ["nick","bob","tom"]` and `<playlist 3>.users = ["bob","jim","rich"]`, playlist2 should be listed first, because it shares 2 users with `@playlist`, while playlist3 only shares 1 user.

I hope I made what I'm trying to do clear enough, but let me know if additional clarification is needed.

**Assocations:**

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_users
  has_many :users, :through => :playlist_users
end

class PlaylistUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :playlist
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_users
  has_many :playlists, :through => :playlist_users
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Playlist.joins(:users)
  .where.not(id: @playlist.id)
  .where(users: {id: @playlist.user_ids})
  .group(:id)
  .order('count(*) desc')
```

Or, if you need to access the result of count(*):

```
@playlists = Playlist.select('playlists.*, count(*) as shared_users_count')
  .joins(...)
  ...
  .order('shared_users_count desc')

# print out shared users count
@playlists.each { |pl| puts pl.shared_users_count }
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! If I print a block with that code: `Playlist.(...).each do |p|`, how can I print out the value of "count(*)"? `p.count(*)` returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

This will simplify your models a little. You have already identified the "has and belongs to many" relationship, this is how to implement it.

First you need only two models. Playlist and User

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :playlists
end
```

Next you need 3 tables.

```
class SampleMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

    create_table :playlists do |t|
      t.string  :name
    end

    create_table :playlists_users, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :playlist
      t.belongs_to :user
    end
  end
end
```

Note that plurals are important in naming collections, for example `has_and_belongs_to_many :users` and as names for your table `create_table :users`.

The join table does not need a model, but does need to be named in alphabetical order and the names pluralised.

Now you can use `user.playlists` to return an array of playlists connected to this user. Being an array you can call `user.playlists[5]` to get the 5th song in the list or you can iterate over it `user.playlists.each do |list|`.

> So if @playlist.users = ["joe","nick","bob"], .users = ["nick","bob","tom"] and .users = ["bob","jim","rich"], playlist2 should be listed first, because it shares 2 users with @playlist, while playlist3 only shares 1 user.

There are two ways you can achieve this. Through a helper method where you retrieve all lists and union them in Rails, or through an SQL query. SQL is faster, but requires knowledge of SQL. Initially I would use Rails and tackle the SQl when there is a gain to be made.

One implementation might be (NOTE: treat this as pseudo code, I have not tested it);

```
# get all the lists
newPlaylist = array.new
users = @playlist.users
users.each do |user|
   newPlaylist = newPlaylist + user.playlists
end

# count all the lists
countPlaylists = Hash.new
newPlaylist.each do |list| 
   if list.in? countPlaylists.keys
       countPlaylists[list] = countPlaylists[list] + 1
   else
       countPlaylists[list] = 1
   end
end

# sort the list - I'm not sure if it sorts on keys or values,
# but either way you should be able to figure it out
countPlaylists.sort
```